# Saving JMeter graph settings

Tags: graph, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Within my JMX file I have customised my graph settings. However the settings are not saved and persisted when I close and reopen Jmeter.

How can I save the graph settings?

---

**Settings:**

I'm losing setting for all the graphs in my test file, both plugins and perfmon graphs, for example;

- Green arrows are switches I have to turn on each time
- Red arrows are switches I have to turn off each time

[image: Settings on a Composite graph]
[image: Settings on a PerfMon graph]

Comment: can you please provide more details on which graph you wanted to save? and steps you followed exactly?

Comment: Hi @Naveen Actually this was with with all the graphs in my JMX file. I've added details to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It depends on the Listener that you are using. Some listeners setting saved in JMX but some won't allow. `jp@gc Perfmon Metrics Collector` might be one of them which don't allow saving the settings (though there is no official word in the documentation of it [here](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)).

Eg:

**For Aggregate Graph settings:**

> Please note: All this parameters aren't saved in JMeter jmx script.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Graph

**For Response Time Graph settings:**

> Please note: All this parameters are saved in JMeter .jmx file.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Time_Graph